# Transparent window with blurred corners

Tags: c++, winapi, user-interface

I want to have a `WS_POPUP` window with blurred edges like this illustration:

[image]

Any suggestions? I've been looking into layered windows but still don't know how I could achieve the full transparent pixels in the edges. Maybe i could put a bitmap over the complete window but how do i make the background transparent? If I have a layered window with a bitmap, the complete bitmap becomes transparent.

Comment: Your link is broken. SO has image tags though.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a layered window (one with the `WS_EX_LAYERED` extended window style set) and provide a 32-bit bitmap with alpha channel using the `UpdateLayeredWindow` function.

The docs for this function are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633556(v=vs.85).aspx

Basically, you no longer use a standard paint loop with `WM_PAINT` but instead just provide a full 32-bit bitmap for the entire contents of the window. Note that the APIs use *premultiplied alpha*, which means that the red, green and blue channel values in the bitmap must be premultiplied with the alpha channel value (explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183393(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Thanks, but where should I call UpdateLayeredWindow? Should it be called on every WM_PAINT? I can't get it to work properly

Comment: I used UpdateLayeredWindow after i created the window and it makes the window ignoring the mouse and none of my controls shows up. [Here's](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39438681/Bilder/StackOverflow/TransparentWindow3.PNG) a screen dump.